# C++ QT Casting to child classes for items in a QList

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, downcast, qlist

I have a QList of type `PrintableObject*` like:

```
QList<PrintableObject*> drawables;
```

This list contains objects of type `PrintableX` which are subclasses of `PrintableObject` inserted like:

```
drawables += &PrintableLine( x, y, x2, y2 );
```

After this I use the list a loop where I do determine the actual type, make a cast and try to use it:

```
foreach(PrintableObject* drawable, drawables){

       if(drawable->myClassName == "PrintableLine") {

           PrintableLine* line = (PrintableLine*) drawable;
           painter.drawLine(line->x, line->y, line->x2, line->y2);

       } else if (drawable->myClassName == "PrintableString") {

           PrintableString* string = (PrintableString*) drawable;
           font.setPointSize(string->fontSize);
           painter.setFont(font);

           painter.drawText(string->x, string->y, string->width, string->height, Qt::AlignHCenter | Qt::AlignTop, string->string "if I say?");

       }

   }
```

Except for, when I try to use my new shiny downcasted object it make a segmentation fault...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you insert a pointer to a dead temporary object into the list:

```
drawables += &PrintableLine( x, y, x2, y2 );
```

Try:

```
drawables += new PrintableLine( x, y, x2, y2 );
```

You may want also to consider adding a virtual ***draw*** method into your *PrintableObject* class to avoid the need of the RTTI and downcast.

Comment: Thanks guy, you have saved my life! A am not a C++ programmer but got to do it anyway. As for RTTI, I know that is a bad thing, but sometimes we all have to write some smelly code :)

Comment: @Zhigalin Happy to save one's life :-) Note: be sure to delete the object that you allocate.